# How to create Session id in xml with the help of XSLT

Tags: xml, spring, xslt, spring-integration

My Expected XML output (the XML I need to be transformed by using XSLT.) :

```
 <DST>
 <DST>
 <PQAWD>
<username>TEST</username> 
<password>Test</password> 
<newPassword /> 
<hostAddress>@@@@@@@@@@</hostAddress> 
<hostPort>@@@@@</hostPort> 
</PQAWD>
</DST>
 <AWDLogon>
<userID>TEST</userID> 
<password encrypt="Y">TRST</password> 
<hostAddress>test</hostAddress> 
<hostPort>@@@@@</hostPort> 
<trace /> 
<readable>N</readable> 
<timeout>120000</timeout> 
<newPassword encrypt="Y" /> 
<config userPrivileges="Y" options="Y" sendRequest="Y" /> 
<currentJobName>PQAWDLogon</currentJobName> 
</AWDLogon>
**<tidx>48006c7898e61461eb110f66a714629864ocx$388111915602261781664778</tidx>** 
</DST>
```

XSL Sheet (which element to be added to get above output)..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version = "1.0">
<xsl:template match="//DST/PQAWD">
<AWDLogon>
<userID><xsl:valueof select="username"/></userID>
<password encrypt="Y"><xsl:valueof select="password"/></password>
<hostAddress><xsl:valueof select="hostAddress"/></hostAddress>
<hostPort><xsl:valueof select="hostPort"/></hostPort>
<trace></trace>
<readable>N</readable>
<timeout>120000</timeout>
<newPassword encrypt="Y"><xsl:valueof select="newPassword"/></newPassword>
<config userPrivileges="Y" options="Y" sendRequest="Y" />
<currentJobName>PQAWDLogon</currentJobName> 
</AWDLogon>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above is the XML ,in that `<tidx>` tag should be acts like session id which is changed   dynamically,
    is there any procedure or tag to add to current XSLT sheet to get above    XML as output, Please help me on this(please consider above xsl sheet as reference)...

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? If XSLT 1.0, which processor specifically?

Comment: sorry to asking u, how to find out my xsl is used by which process?,I am new to xml and xslt files ...please help me on this..

Comment: How will you run (execute) the transformation?

Comment: i am using this website for conversion http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html#ad-output ,but internally i am not able to get it how it process and which process,please suggest me if i am wrong....

Comment: michael.hor257k, do u have any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Integration `<int-xml:xslt-transformer>` supports `<int-xml:xslt-param>`. Hance you can provide to the XSLT template any variable:

```
<int-xml:xslt-transformer input-channel="xsltChannel"
                              output-channel="output"
                              xsl-resource="classpath:myTemplate.xslt">
     <int-xml:xslt-param name="sessionId" expression="[ANY_VALID_SPEL_HERE]"/>
</int-xml:xslt-transformer>
```

Where your xslt should have this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="sessionId"/>

    <xsl:template match="//DST/PQAWD">
            ....
           <tidx>
              <xsl:value-of select="$sessionId" />
           </tidx>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

More info is here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/xml.html#xml-transformer-namespace

Comment: [Headers={timestamp=1401709356294, id=6a83b09e-f874-2d51-b016-106584460372, correlationId=e7d46888-4697-0669-3ab6-6cf4112509bb, jobDesignerJobName=PQAWDLogon, sequenceSize=1, originalPayload=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><DST>
               <PQAWD>
                  <username>DT77214</username>
                  <password>Passwd@1</password>
                  <newPassword/>
               </PQAWD>
            </DST>, sequenceNumber=1}] this is header part ,which thing i need to be replaced with expression="[ANY_VALID_SPEL_HERE]",please can you help on this..

Comment: First of all you should explain what is `sessionId` in your case. It might be just enough to use that unique `id` from message headers. It is your domain and we can't determine the busines logic

Comment: i have tried with "header.jobDesignerJobName" but i am getting empty tag like <tidx/> ,which thing i need to put which is there in header part as defined  above ..

Comment: session id means random number which is generating for every log in ,for example :<tidx>48006c7898e61461eb110f66a714629864ocx$388111915602261781664778</tidx>

Comment: Well. Just generate it and place to the message header before XSLT

Comment: u mean to say ,we should write logic in java ?

Comment: generating for session id , we need to write servlet also, so is it accessible from configuration file..

Comment: Maybe. I don't know if you already have that generate value, or you have to do it manually. `UUID.randomUUID()` can be used directly from SpEL without any Java code

Comment: please suggest me how to generate the session id and keep into that headers (please give me skeleton so that i will go forward with this
)

Comment: If you are in the `ServletRequest` you can get the `sessionId`: `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSessionId()`. And also from SpEL

Comment: <int-xml:xslt-transformer xsl-resource="${stylesheet.PQAWDLogonStage4}"  >
   <int-xml:xslt-param name="sessionId" expression="UUID.randomUUID()"/>
  </int-xml:xslt-transformer> is this ur telling about

Comment: Of course don't. You SpEL is poor. Should be `expression="T(java.util.UUID).randomUUID()"`

Comment: yes artem its working , i hope its enough for moving forward , i think it would have not create the problem in future...

Comment: Good to know! Well, let's apply the answer and go ahead with docs to study something new